# Modify a mixed-effects formula in R

Tags: r, formula, lme4, mixed-models

I have a formula:

```
my_formula <- a ~ b + (1|d) + e
```

I want to programmatically remove the `e` variable from this formula.

What I've done for fixed-effects only formulae is:

```
drop_es <- function(f) {
    e_idxs <- grep(pattern = 'e',
                   x = all.vars(f[[3]]))

    stats::formula(stats::drop.terms(termobj = stats::terms(f),
                                     dropx = e_idxs,
                                     keep.response = TRUE))
}
```

This works on fixed-effects only formula:

```
drop_es(f = a ~ b + e)
```

> a ~ b

But on a formula with a random effect, it drops the parentheses:

```
drop_es(f = a ~ b + (1|d) + e)
```

> a ~ b + 1 | d

This is a really important distinction -- without the parentheses, it is interpreted as:

```
a ~ b|d
```

How can I remove the `e` terms without losing the parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `update` function exists to modify formulas. use

```
update(my_formula, ~.-e)
# a ~ b + (1 | d)
```

The `-e` means drop the "e" term from the formula while `.` means keep everything else.

Comment: I wonder how much more base R I don't know about...Thanks, Flick!